# Getting "set statistics io on" results in t-sql for tuning

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, io, statistics

I want to add monitoring capabilities to a complex process involving many stored procedures.
In some cases I want to capture the number of logical reads produced by a single statement.

In other words, I would like to turn on the `set statistics io on`, access (and save the results to a log table) what is usually displayed in the SSMS in the "messages" tab.

I saw that it can be done in .Net with SqlInfoMessageEventHandler. I'm sure that it can also be done in T-SQL but i didn't find it yet.

Thanks!

---

Logical_reads in sys.dm_exec_requests is not increasing as well...

The perfect solution for me would be a way of somehow capturing the "set statistics io on" information :

```
select name, id
    from   sysobjects
    union all 
    select name,id
    from   sysobjects  ;


(120 row(s) affected)
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [dynamic management views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188068%28SQL.110%29.aspx), available in 2008 and up.  For example, to determine the number of reads done by your query, you could:

```
declare @start_reads bigint
select @start_reads = reads from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = @@spid

-- Your query here 

select reads - @start_reads from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = @@spid
```

There's basically two types of counters:

- The `_session_` views have counters that are incremented after your current batch completes.
- The `_exec_` counters start at 0 and increment while your batch is running.

Comment: Thanks!
It looks like the correct direction but i have 2 problems here :
1. The "reads" column is not being updated. Maybe it is only the physical reads that are exposed here ?
2. When i'm making a join between 2 tables, the "set statistics io" option shows the number of logical reads the engine made for each of the tables. The technique you propose does not expose this kind of information.

Comment: Yeah, especially if you run a query twice it will be cached and no `reads` are required.  You can check `cpu_time` instead, but make sure the query uses a measurable amount of CPU.  For logical reads, check the `logical_reads` column.